# recombining 32 bit integer from 8 bit components

Tags: c++, binary, bit-manipulation

I have read 4 chars from a file. For instance 11110000 00001111 11000011 00111100  read in that order. i need to combine these from individual chars to form a continuous single uint32_t 11110000000011111100001100111100. Here is a solution i decided that seemed to work until it didn't.

```cpp
//#include <fstream>

#include <cstdint>

#include <iostream>

//std::fstream File("example", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out | std::ios::in);

char FileDataExpectedResult[4] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0D};
char FileDataUnexpectedResult[4] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x64};

uint32_t Reasemble(char* FileDataArray) 
{
    uint32_t Result=0x0;
    
    char ComponentByte;

    for (int ByteIterator=0; ByteIterator<4; ByteIterator++ ) 
    {
        //File.read(&ComponentByte, 1);
        ComponentByte = FileDataArray[ByteIterator];

        uint32_t ExtendedComponentByte = 0x0000 | ComponentByte;

        Result = Result | (ExtendedComponentByte << ((32/(ByteIterator+1)-8)));
    }

    return Result;
}

int main() {
    
    uint32_t Expected = Reasemble(FileDataExpectedResult);
    uint32_t Unexpected = Reasemble(FileDataUnexpectedResult);

    std::cout << "hopefully 13: " << (int)Expected << "\n";
    std::cout << "hopefully 868: " << (int)Unexpected << "\n";

    return 1;
}
```

this code is recreated in a simpler environment stripped of context. When this code reads 0x0000000D from a file it correctly converts it to 13. However, 0x00000364 returns 108 instead of the expected 868. The idea was is reading byte by byte then putting it in a 32bit number and shifting it depending on what byte it should be in the 32bit number, then or'ing each one with a singular 32 bit number to combine them.

Comment: Tip: It's a dominant convention in C++ to have variable names that are at least initially lower-case, as in `result` instead of `Result`.

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean in technical terms?

Comment: Why not read all 4 bytes and shuffle them as necessary?

Comment: produced a result different to the intended one.

Comment: I need the result to be one singular integer i can convert to int and use as a number

Comment: Please explain in *technical terms*, not vague descriptions of abstract problems. "Different result" is the first part of a diagnostic. We cannot help you do it in a "different" form without knowing specifics.

Comment: What [endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) form are you trying to assemble? Why can't you use existing implementations of things like [`ntohl`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl)?

Comment: `Result` is uninitialized.

Comment: `int main() { return 1; }` ? You also have some code that actually does something, right? The one that doesnt work like you expect? Please post a [mcve] toghether with example input, actual and expected output

Comment: Most probably you have issue when 8th bit is set as your `char` is signed.

Comment: its either reading from the file or the conversion that has the error, assuming reading from the file is ok, you can use hardcoded input.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/b6ovn48s1 might be better as a [mre]

Comment: I've had trouble with sign extension of `char` in the past. I'd use `ExtendedComponentByte = ComponentByte & 0xff`.

Comment: `((32/(ByteIterator+1)-8))` gives 24, 8, 2 and 0, might be where you want to focus your debugging efforts

Comment: loop might be overkill, `return byte0 | (byte1 << 8) | (byte2 << 16) | (byte3 << 24);` would do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in `((32/(ByteIterator+1)-8))` -- I'm sure that's not what you want. I think `(24 - (ByteIterator*8))` is what you were aiming for.

However, there are library functions for this sort of thing (tadman suggested ntohl).